# Load MVC Kendo Grid Fluent Settings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to replace the column grid definition in the razor page with GridColumnSettings set in the controller. The option I am having a problem with is the Fluent

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Freight).Width(250).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("gte")));
```

Options that are available in the grid definition that aren't available in GridColumnSettings. How can I expose this functionality in the  GridColumnSettings class?  I'm doing this for two reasons; One is to make the order of the columns dynamic and to make defining the Kendo grid easier.

```
public ActionResult ColumnSettings()
{
    var columns = new[] 
    {
        new GridColumnSettings
        {
            Member = "ProductName", 
            Width = "200px"
        },
        new GridColumnSettings
        {
            Member = "UnitPrice",
            Width = "130px",
            Format = "{0:c}",
        },
        new GridColumnSettings
        {
            Member = "UnitsInStock",
            Width = "130px"
        }
    }

ViewData["Columns"] = columns;

return View(SessionProductRepository.All());


}

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns => columns.LoadSettings((IEnumerable<GridColumnSettings>)ViewData["Columns"]))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Product_Read", "Grid"))
        )
)
```

Comment: If this is Kendo Grid, it should be `@(Html.Kendo().Grid`

Comment: Yes, it should be.  I corrected that line.

Comment: I don't know why you wanna do this, when Kendo Grid already gives the user the option to re-order the columns or add/remove them.

Comment: Also, your controller action has syntax errors. You're ViewData assignment and return statement must be outside of the columns definition.

Comment: I would be able to generate views for models without having to write much razor code in the view.  I can iterate over object fields and create GridColumnSettings for each item.